# Learning to code in Python. Can't figure out how to use conditionals based on UDP payload

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, server, udp

I have LIFX lights and a VOIP phone system.  I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a light to turn on or off based on if a phone is in use.  When a user picks up or hangs up a handset, the phone broadcasts its state over UDP 2088.

Using Wireshark, I know that the payload for offhook is 0b1f1001c0a8fa33dcd19b200000000813ed020412020066 
and the payload for on-hook is 0b1f1001c0a8fa33dcd19b200000000813ed000412020066  (although if I copy straight from Wireshark, it inserts colons when I paste 0b:1f:10:01:c0...)

I've figured out how to turn my office light on or off using the LIFXLan module and have gotten to the point where I can trigger lights manually by sending plaintext from a client to a server listening on whatever UDP port.  However, I'm stuck at trying to use data from the phones to trigger the lights.   I'm not 100% sure it can be done, in fact.  My code is as follows:

```
import Bulb_Off
import Bulb_On
import sys
import socket
import codecs
import binascii
#I may have imported unnecessary modules

UDP_PORT = 2088
OFF_HOOK = "0b1f1001c0a8fa33dcd19b200000000813ed020412020066" 
ON_HOOK = "0b1f1001c0a8fa33dcd19b200000000813ed000412020066" #I am hoping I can simply match the data in the data field of the packet

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    if data == ON_HOOK:
        Bulb_Off.main()
        print "received message:", data
        print "1"

    elif data == OFF_HOOK:
        Bulb_On.main()
        print "received message:", data
        print "2"
    else:
        print data
```

The output I usually get is gibberish such as al▒.~5Vn]D▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

I know I have to convert the payload, but I've been stuck (I just started yesterday.)  I'm guessing this is something extremely easy or ridiculously hard.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out.  Needed to add
.decode("hex")
to the end of the declarations for ON_HOOK and OFF_HOOK